# Empty Query error when submitting form

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Apologies as this is a duplicate question, but for some reason I wasn't able to make any comments on the answers I received and the question hasn't been answered.

When my form is submitted (via Ajax), I'm getting the following error message:

> **PHP Warning:**  `mysqli_query()` [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in /home1/xenongro/public_html/testing/enrolment/thanks.php on line 32

I have a suspicion that it's something to do with the if/else statements, but not sure what the actual problem is. As a test, I removed the if/else statements and successfully submitted a few values from the form. Unfortunately when I made it conditional, it came up with the above error.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fname']));
$lastname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lname']));
$worktel = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['worktel']));
$funding = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['funding']));
$level = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['level']));

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', '<xxxx>', 'xxxx')
or die ('Could not connect to MySQL server.');

if ($level != "IOSH Managing Safely"){
    if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
        $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
        "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
        $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
        "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
}
else if ($level == "IOSH Managing Safely"){
    if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
        $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
        "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
        $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
        "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
}

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die ('error querying database');
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: Add an `else` case. If you don't, `$query` will be empty (raising your error)

Comment: It might be helpful to see the correct indention of your code, especially the conditional blocks using if/else/else if. Maybe it clears up things for yourself as well. Furthermore: Don't use `else if` where not needed: `$level != "IOSH Managing Safely"` is distinct from `$level == "IOSH Managing Safely"`, right? So for example, here a single `else` should cover this exclusive or case.

Comment: I've posted a case, when `$query` will become empty. btw, why are you checking this conditions, if query is the same for all 4 branches? The code you posted is equal to single if: `if ($funding == "Self Funding" || $funding == "Employer Funding") { /*query here*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

as you are using else if execute the query inside the else if block and revert back in comments

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) //Inside the else if block
```

Comment: It would be better to check if `$query` is not null instead of putting `mysqli_query()` into each else-if block.

Comment: if it doesn't satisfy the condition, it will not enter the block,so doesn't take up much load..

Answer (score 0):

if you are posting via ajax and using jquery, you should at first submit like this, otherwise it won't take any post value to the ajax url

```
$.ajax ({
        type:'post',
        url:"domainPath",
        success: function(response) {
            if(!response.trim()) { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$funding` is not equal to both "Self Funding" and "Employer Funding", `$query` will be empty.
Otherwise `$query` cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (in $ErrorsRow you can marge all form errors):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
    $Data = $_POST;
    foreach ($Data as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $DataRow[$key] = htmlspecialchars(trim($value));
        } else {
            $ErrorsRow[] = 'Empty field '. $key;
        }
    }

    if($DataRow && !isset($ErrorsRow)){
        $firstname = $DataRow['fname'];
        $lastname  = $DataRow['lname'];
        $worktel   = $DataRow['worktel'];
        $funding   = $DataRow['funding'];
        $level     = $DataRow['level'];

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', '<xxxx>', 'xxxx')
    or die ('Could not connect to MySQL server.');

    if ($level != "IOSH Managing Safely"){
     if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
      $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
    "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
    $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
    "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    }
    else if ($level == "IOSH Managing Safely"){
    if ($funding == "Self Funding"){
    $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
    "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
    }
    else if ($funding == "Employer Funding"){
    $query = "INSERT INTO enrolments (fname, lname, worktel)" . 
    "VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$worktel')";
        }
        }
    if(isset($query)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('error querying database');
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }


    } else {
        if(isset($ErrorsRow) && !empty(implode($ErrorsRow))){
            $Errors = implode(',', $ErrorsRow);
            echo 'some error message'. $Errors; 
        }

    } 
}
```